# Conditionally Insert Where Clause in LINQ Method Syntax with Select Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Not sure if this possible using the LINQ method chain syntax or at all, but I would like to conditionally insert a where class in the chain if a parameter passed to the method is not null.

Here is the redundant code I would like to simplify:

```
public ICollection<Organization> getNetworkServiceRecipients(string serviceId = null)
{
    ICollection<Organization> children = get_all_children();
    if (serviceId != null)
    {
        return children.SelectMany(o => o.receives_these_services)
                        .Where(s => s.serviceId == serviceId)
                        .Select(o => o.serviceRecipient)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return (children.SelectMany(o => o.receives_these_services)
                        .Select(o => o.serviceRecipient)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList());
    }
}
```

I have been trying to insert the where clause programmatically based on whether serviceId is null or not. All of the answers I have found where based on the query syntax, but I couldn't translate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have it in the actual where query as dotnetom mentioned, you can do something like this:

```
public ICollection<Organization> getNetworkServiceRecipients(string serviceId = null)
{
    var services = get_all_children().SelectMany(o => o.receives_these_services);
    if (serviceId != null)
        services = services.Where(s => s.serviceId == serviceId);

    return services.Select(o => o.serviceRecipient)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I prefer this one for readability. But the ones below work as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This approach is far superior. Many devs unfortunately don't realize that you can build a LINQ query across multiple lines of code (allowing for use of constructs like `if`, `foreach`, etc. to do powerful things). As long as you don't call something evaluative like `ToList()`, the query is not issued to the DB until the end.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this approach:

```
public ICollection<Organization> getNetworkServiceRecipients(string serviceId = null)
{
    ICollection<Organization> children = get_all_children();

    return children.SelectMany(o => o.receives_these_services)
                .Where(s => serviceId == null || s.serviceId == serviceId)
                .Select(o => o.serviceRecipient)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
}
```

In this case if your variable `serviceId` is null then only the first part of where condition would be executed, otherwise first part would be true and only second condition would matter.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer as dotnetom, but uses a ternary to determine which lambda to use
so that `serviceId == null` doesn't get executed on a per-item basis.

```
return children.SelectMany(o => o.receives_these_services)
            .Where( serviceId == null ? (_ => true) : (s => s.serviceId == serviceId))
            .Select(o => o.serviceRecipient)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```